# Figures on svg canvas

Tags: javascript, svg

I programmatically create several svg-images by JavaScript. Images are lines.

```
function create(elem) {                         //function for create svg elem                           
    var svg = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    return document.createElementNS(svg, elem);

function set(elem, atrArr) {       //function for set attributes svg elem                      
    for (var i in atrArr) {
        elem.setAttribute(i, atrArr[i])
    }
}


function someFunc(valueWidth, valueHeight) {
   var SVG = create('svg');   //canvas
   var line = create('line');  //line

   var width = valueWidth;   //some value
   var heigth = valueHeight;  //some value

   set(SVG, {             //set canvas
       version: '1.1',
       width: width,
       height: height
   });

   //set line
   set(line, { x1: 0, x2: width, y1: 0, y2: height, style: 'stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1' });     

   SVG.style.position = 'absolute';
   SVG.appendChild(line);
}
```

If height or width < 0.5, then line is drawn only in IE.
Can I draw line in other browsers without changing the size of the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me in Chrome, after correcting the syntax errors (height vs heigth), and appending the svg element to the body:

```
var SVG = create('svg');   //canvas
document.body.appendChild(SVG);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4jRZT/5/

Comment: I wrote " heigth"? =)

Comment: :)) yes, it seems like there's a threshold for lines less than a pixel wide...oh well, you probably need to scale it then

Comment: But in IE it work) I think.. Is it feature or bug? =)) Because the line is drawn correctly and line width doen't change even if it's bigger than canvas width)